# Java.unknownhostexception in android client app

Tags: java, android, exception, dns

Recently we are seeing the unknownhostexception randomly in the android app suddenly it stops sending the data but once we restart the mobile data or wifi it again sends the data.

We are not able to reproduce this so often but this is causing so many problems for us in our production where we not able to sync the data to server.

Attaching few logs

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "fieldview.verayu.com": No address associated with hostname

09-12 15:06:19.975 3077-4533/com.nivaata.verayusaas W/System.err:     at      
java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:473)

09-12 15:06:19.975 3077-4533/com.nivaata.verayusaas W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:253)

09-12 15:06:19.975 3077-4533/com.nivaata.verayusaas W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:216)

09-12 15:06:19.975 3077-4533/com.nivaata.verayusaas W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)

09-12 15:06:19.975 3077-4533/com.nivaata.verayusaas W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)

09-12 15:06:19.976 3077-4533/com.nivaata.verayusaas W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)

09-12 15:06:19.976 3077-4533/com.nivaata.verayusaas W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:452)

09-12 15:06:19.976 3077-4533/com.nivaata.verayusaas W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:592)

09-12 15:06:19.976 3077-4533/com.nivaata.verayusaas W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:512)

09-12 15:06:19.976 3077-4533/com.nivaata.verayusaas W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:490)

09-12 15:06:19.976 3077-4533/com.nivaata.verayusaas W/System.err:     at com.nivaata.verayusaas.utils.FieldViewUtils.uploadFormWithPicture(FieldViewUtils.java:572)
```

Comment: seems like something broken in your network request url , it's clear there is something wrong happen with your url when you form this request ..as log also says `No address associated with hostname`

Comment: attached some logs please check

Comment: Maybe the network is not reachable. try with `http:// or https://` Try to ping it from device.

Comment: there can be some other rare reasons too , like low bandwidth , unstable network and yeah follow the advise of @MadhukarHebbar

Comment: Could it be your firewall settings that denied your access to the URL at your organization? Ask your system admin.

Comment: we are trying to https:// url and also we are seeing this issue only for some data sync but when we are trying to sync other data and pushes to the mobile are well received